# Interactive sorting inside merged report

Tags: winforms, devexpress

I am creating a report (DevExpress 17.1) that is merged from multiple other reports. I'm trying to provide interactive sorting for one of these reports but after clicking on the column header, instead of table sort, the whole document dissappears with text similar to "no pages to display". I'm setting interactive sorting according to this article:

https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument5527

and this is how my creating code looks like:

```
public override void Print()
{
    ListReport listReport =
        new ListReport {DataSource = state.RetrievedList};
    var report = new XtraReport();

    report.CreateDocument(false);

    var reports = new XtraReport[] {new OtherReport(state), listReport};

    foreach (var item in reports)
    {
        item.CreateDocument(false);
        report.Pages.AddRange(item.Pages);
    }

    report.PrintingSystem.ContinuousPageNumbering = true;

    using (var printTool = new ReportPrintTool(report))
    {
        printTool.ShowRibbonPreviewDialog();
    }
}
```

However, as soon as I change method to print only the list then report interactive sorting starts working properly. This how it looks when it works:

```
ListReport listReport =
    new ListReport {DataSource = state.RetrievedList};

using (var printTool = new ReportPrintTool(listReport))
{
    printTool.ShowRibbonPreviewDialog();
}
```

How would I make it to work in my case?

Answer (score 0):

The preview dialog regenerates document pages on changing sort order. But it can not regenerate pages from different reports. This is a product limitation.
I suggest you to use the [subreports](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument5175). It should works propertly.

Comment: It seems not to be working as subreport also. There is no triangle above the column. However, I can click on the column but there is no changes at all.

Comment: can you share your problematic repx? i think this feature must just works!